# Developing a custom SPA for browsing and uploading to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

Is it possible to deploy an SPA on AWS that calls Amazon S3 APIs?
The SPA will act as a custom S3 browser app, where I want to be able to deploy, delete, etc documents that are stored in a S3 instance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly deploy a Single Page app written in the language of your choice and then use the corresponding AWS SDK to invoke S3 operations. For example, you can write a SPA in JS that uses the Amazon S3 JavaScript API to perform S3 CRUD operations on Amazon S3 content. Likewise, you can develop a SPA in Java and then use the Java S3 API.

Once you develop your app, you can deploy it to the cloud by deploying it to an EC2 instance. Using Elastic Beanstalk makes it easy to deploy an App to the cloud.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's possible to deploy a SPA on AWS S3. Adding medium article for reference https://medium.com/@joecrobak/production-deploy-of-a-single-page-app-using-s3-and-cloudfront-d4aa2d170aa3.
Though you need to other AWS services as well like `route 53` and `cloudfront`

Comment: Hello, thanks for taking the time to answer me :)
What I want to do is not deploy an SPA on a S3, but an SPA that is deployed let's day on a S3 or Aws Amplify, but that can access another S3 where documents are hosted, using the S3 APIs of this last instance.

Comment: Ah! I don't know the answer and it would require some research.